# Is it possible to print the label of the object instead the id in material ui DataGrid

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui, datagrid

So I have two tables in my database. I want a DataGrid UI to print all my columns except the categoryId I want to print a label instead (like in selection valueOptions) :

```
const columns: GridColDef = [
    {
        "field": "title",
        "headerName": "Titel",
        "width": 350,
        "editable": true
    },
    {
        "field": "categoryId",
        "headerName": "Kategorie",
        "width": 250,
        "editable": true,
        "type": "singleSelect",
        "valueOptions": [
            {
                "value": "miv560972ynqzk9",
                "label": "stuff 1"
            },
            {
                "value": "1t7n08l9tfdwotn",
                "label": "stuff 2"
            },
        ]
    }
]

const rows: GridRowsProp = [
    {
        "categoryId": "miv560972ynqzk9",
        "title": "Lineare Algebra Hausaufga",
    },
    {
        "categoryId": "1t7n08l9tfdwotn",
        "title": "Test",
    },
]
```

So I want something like this:

```
const rows: GridRowsProp = [
    {
        "categoryId": { value:"miv560972ynqzk9", label: "stuff1"},
        "title": "Lineare Algebra Hausaufga",
    },
    {
        "categoryId": { value: "1t7n08l9tfdwotn", label: "stuff2" },
        "title": "Test",
    },
]
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow ! Can you show the code you tried ? You can read [ask], SO isn't a free coding service

Comment: I posted the code?

Comment: No, you posted json or base, but you didn't post what you tried